# Select statement with where clause Like in array

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-like

I know how to perform an SQL LIKE % query for a single value like so:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM Farmers WHERE Available_products LIKE ('%Bananas%')";`

but how do I do this if the search terms for my LIKE comes from an array? For example, let's say we have an array like this:

```
$_POST['Products']="Cacaos,Bananas";
$array=implode(',', $_POST['Products']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Farmers WHERE Available_products LIKE ('%$array%')";
```

I want to get all the records in database that the column `Available_Products` contains Cacaos or Bananas or Both

Comment: Try using sql where in

Comment: `LIKE '%Bananas%' OR LIKE '%Cacaos%' OR LIKE '%AnythingElse%'`

Comment: @Akintunde `IN` does exact matching, not patterns.

Comment: Be careful when inserting data from outside into your query. You should always sanitize everything which you cannot trust.

Comment: @miron Or better yet, prepare the query and use placeholders for the values ;-)

Comment: The content in the array may differ each time with value i take from the user

Comment: @NewDeveloper I think you've mixed up `implode` with `explode` in your code snippet. `explode()` is what will "convert" your Products string to an array. `implode()` is what will format your array into a string to put into your query.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$_POST['Products'] = array("Cacaos", "Bananas");` since you said the search terms are in an array?

Comment: @Barmar you are right, I got them as a result of another SQL statement, which I don't know how to loop to put the result in an array `$stmt ="SELECT distinct Category_ID FROM Order_Product where Order_ID ='".$_POST["OrderID"]."'";
  $CategoryName = array();

  foreach ($conn->query($stmt) as $row) 
  {
   $Cat = $row['Category_ID'];
   
   $query ="SELECT distinct Category_Name FROM Categories where Category_ID=$Cat";
   $row1 = $conn->query($query)->fetch();
   $catname = $row1['Category_Name'];
   $cats=array_push($CategoryName,$catname);
  }` this will be the output of ajax,help?

Comment: Why don't you join the tables instead of doing separate queries?

Comment: See @clementakis's answer where he creates a temporary table and joins with it. You should be able to do that with the above table query instead of creating a temporary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the array to a regular expression and use `REGEX` instead of `LIKE`

```
$_POST['Products'] = array('Cacaos', 'Bananas');
$regex = implode('|', $_POST['Products']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Farmers WHERE Available_products REGEX :regex";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':regex', $regex);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @Barmar Out of curiosity, would this REGEX generally perform better than a reasonable number of OR statements (say 10 items in the array)? For example `$where="WHERE Available_products like '%" . implode("%' or Available_Products like '%", $_POST['Products']) ."%'";` Since it's not bothering to use the index anyway?

Comment: You'd have to benchmark it to be sure, but I'd expect it to be about the same or better. Neither of them can use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the help of REGEXP .

```
 $_POST['Products']="Cacaos,Bananas";
 $array=implode('|', $_POST['Products']); 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM Farmers WHERE   
              Available_products REGEXP". $array;
```

Comment: I got this error `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Bananas' at line 2`

Comment: If you don't use a prepared statement, you need quotes around the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like :

```
// Populating join table.    
CREATE TABLE temp_table_myArray (myArray nvarchar(255));
    INSERT INTO temp_table_myArray (myArray) VALUES ('Cacaos');
    INSERT INTO temp_table_myArray (myArray) VALUES ('Bananas');

// Query using the join table.
    SELECT F.*
    FROM Farmers AS F
        INNER JOIN temp_table_myArray AS T ON (F.Available_products LIKE(CONCAT('%',T.myArray,'%')));
```

But I think there is a better PHP way to solve your problem...